# Is the music in the main menu specifically made for the game?

Tags: project-igi

The background music in the main menu of Project IGI is great! Can anyone tell me where it's from, or was it specifically composed for the game?

Comment: @bakkelun Acceptance is an optional action.  There doesn't need to be any reason or obligation to accept answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Kim M. Jensen** composed and recorded all the background scores for IGI 1 and IGI 2, so the main menu music you're refering to was for that game.

After the great feedback he got for his work on the soundtrack of the first game in 1999, he was called in to also do the soundtrack for the sequel: Project I.G.I 2.

You can listen to some of his music here: https://soundcloud.com/kim-m-jensen

You can read more about him here: http://igi.wikia.com/wiki/Kim_Jensen

Also; here is the main music you're refering to: